# How to track an application contains more than 300 events

Tags: android, flurry

My application contains 450 events. While trying to check a sample application contains 500 events using flurry, the Event summary list displays 300 events only. Is there is any tool to track my application?

Comment: I think that Flurry has a maximum number of Events to catch

Comment: There is a limit of 300 events that can be tracked per app. Also, there is a limit of 10 parameters that can be tracked per event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only real option is to make some common events amalgamating things and destinguishing with parameters.  Getting the data out of flurry you will need to download the .csv file for detailed analisis.

As an example I have an event dedicated to reporting various exceptions that I catch.  I use the same event but then have a parameter for the class, the message form the exception a custom message form the code.  I then fill in parameted with fixed names that get filled with my custom data.